# Pytorch (0.4.1) can not find GPU (Nvidia V100)

Tags: pytorch

I have installed Pytorch(0.4.1) with CUDA 9.0 via anaconda.
I also have installed Nvidia driver (390.30).
Through nvidia-smi, I can see all GPUs(V100) with their situation.
But I always get False when calling torch.cuda.is_avaliable().
I also tried to downgrade the CUDA version from 9.0 to 8.0, but the situation was just the same.
Tried to install Pytorch again but nothing changed. Could anyone give me a hand, please?

Comment: have you installed cuda and cudnn from nvidia's site? have you tried cuda 9.2?

Comment: Just checked. I too face the same issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's a Nvidia container issue.
After downgrading the Nvidia container from 18.08 to 18.07, all code runs well.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to let anaconda handle everything by itself. For the time being, I have pytorch version 0.2, cudatoolkit version 7.5, cudnn version 5.1. It works fine. You can try

```
conda update --all
```

It should solve all the conflicts.